# How to connect to Bluetooth SPP using dot42?

Tags: android, bluetooth, dot42

After reading the dot42 comments and trolling Java examples I managed to setup a Bluetooth connection but fail to open the connection. I cannot determine the problem. I followed the docs step by step.

My target device is a HTC Explorer running on 2.3 Gingerbread. Here is my code.

```
//Target 2.3 (Gingerbread)
[assembly: Application("dot42Application1")]

[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.BLUETOOTH)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)]

namespace dot42Application1
{
    [Activity]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        private TextView txStatus;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstance);
            SetContentView(R.Layouts.MainLayout);

            // Find UI controls
            txStatus = FindViewById<TextView>(R.Ids.txStatus);

            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE); 

            var bt = BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter();

            if (bt != null) //If device has not Bluetooth this will be null
            {
                if (bt.IsEnabled()) //Is Bluetooth device enabled?
                {
                    var BT_My_Addr = bt.Address; //Get the devices MAC
                    var BT_Bonded = bt.GetBondedDevices().ToList(); //Get a list of bonded devices- I bonded to a BT2TTL Board earlier.

                    txStatus.Text = BT_My_Addr + System.Environment.NewLine; //Shows my MAC on screen.

                    string BT_Remote_Address = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var BTDevice in BT_Bonded) //Just searchging for string in bonded list
                    {
                        if (BTDevice.Name.Contains("linvor"))  
                        {
                            BT_Remote_Address = BTDevice.Address;
                        }
                    }

                    //Gets remote device
                    var BT_Remote_Device = bt.GetRemoteDevice(BT_Remote_Address);

                    //Create a RFCOMM Socket to remote device using popular UUID ofr BT Serial boards
                    var BTsocket = BT_Remote_Device.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

                    //Call anyway to make sure there is no discvoerry in the backgorund. It slows stuff down.
                    bt.CancelDiscovery(); 

                    //Exception here? Dont know why :(
                    BTsocket.Connect();

                    //Suppsoed to dump 0 to 99999 to my listening serial device but I never get this far.
                    var BT_Out = BTsocket.GetOutputStream();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
                    {
                        BT_Out.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(i.ToString()));

                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    txStatus.Text = "Bluetooth is disabled :(";
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

And this is what it shows after the socket creation

[image]

and the error...

[image]

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved the problem by analysing various code snippets on the internet. I think the problem was trying to do everything in the `OnCreate` method.  The steps I followed are the following:

- Created a button on the main view (MainActivity.xml) and attached a onClick method.

[image]

- Moved all the code OUT of the `OnCreate` method. (I think this allows the application to fully initialise.) Created an event handler for the button with two methods.

[image]

- The two methods are the same as the code I posted in my original question. Just they are separated out and called when the user clicks the button.

  - `findBT()` Gets the default adapter. Checks if Bluetooth is enabled if not does the intent filter. Or if it is it will cycle through the bonded list and match a device name and store the BluetoohDevice in a variable. *This is another thing that is different from my code. I do not use GetRemoteDevice I just assign the device from the BondedList to my global variable.*

[image]

[image]

- `openBT()` creates the RFCOMM socket (this did not work with unsecure - it threw an exception but using the secure method worked!)

[image]

You have to pair to the remote device using the Androids Bluetooth control panel. This code will not scan or connect to devices that are not paired. It will just throw null exceptions.

**Also I left the target SDK 2.3.x but I am using the 4.x API.**

*-Disclosure. I am not a seasoned Android developer and just learning about the life cycle of Java applications in the Android context. I hope this can help other C# developers trying to do the same.*